# Export fonts from a package - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Page URL: [https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/package-fonts.html][1]

Page source: [https://github.com/flutter/website/tree/master/src/docs/cookbook/design/package-fonts.md][1]

Description of issue:

I've been trying to replicate the project **Export fonts from a package** from the Flutter.dev cookbook page. But I'm getting lost in the instructions. The instructions indicate that :

> To export a font from a package, you need to import the font files into the lib folder of **the package project**.

The instructions also say that (I quote)

> assume you’ve got a Flutter library called awesome_package with fonts living in a lib/fonts folder.

And the `awesome_package` package/library folder structure is defined as follow

```
awesome_package/
  lib/
    awesome_package.dart
    fonts/
      Raleway-Regular.ttf
      Raleway-Italic.ttf
```

My question is : How do I create the `awesome_package`. Do I necessarily need to publish the package on the pub.dev ?

Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I create the awesome_package.

See more about Flutter [packages and plugins](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages)

> Do I necessarily need to publish the package on the pub.dev ?

No, you can use the package locally.

If you just want to use differents fonts, don't create a package for this, use this package [google_fonts](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts)

Or you can use your own font

[Docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts#supported-font-formats)

```yaml
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: font_name
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/font_name1.ttf
        - asset: fonts/font_name1.ttf
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It serves me very well